# Linux コマンドでテキストファイルにヘッダーとフッターを追加したい

Tags: linux, shellscript, sed

Linuxコマンドで以下のようにテキストファイル (test.txt) を加工したいです。

**加工前:**

```
-- SQL
```

**加工後:**

```
header
-- SQL
footer
```

以下のようなシェルスクリプトを実行してもうまくいきませんでした。
うまくいく方法を教えていただけますと嬉しいです。

test.sh

```bash
# not foundになる。
sed -i '1s/^/header\\n/' test.txt

# なぜかtest.txt・というファイル名が作られる
echo footer >> test.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` を使わない別の例です。

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "header" >> result.txt
cat test.txt  >> result.txt
echo "footer" >> result.txt
```

Comment: `{ echo 'header'; cat test.txt; echo 'footer'; } > result.txt`

Answer (score 3):

質問のコードに大きな間違いは有りません。このコードで「not foundになる」「test.txt・というファイル名が作られる」という現象は起きません。色々と試している時に、なにか手順を誤ったのでしょう。

小さな間違いとして、`\\n` が有ります。これは `\n` が正しいです。(`\n` が使えるのは GNU 拡張のようですが、そもそも `-i` オプションが GNU 拡張なので、使える環境だと考えられます)

Answer (score 1):

```bash
$ sed -i -E -e '1iheader' -e '$afooter' test.txt
$ cat test.txt
header
-- SQL
footer
```

Comment: thank you so much.I,m resoleved.